# Warning: syslog() has been disabled for security reason

Tags: warnings, syslog, magento-2.3

I use magento 2.3, fresh installed
mode: developer

After installing extension I try to execute  *php bin/magento setup:upgrade* , but that don't work. I get an warning message

```
"Warning: syslog() has been disabled for security reasons in .../magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SyslogHandler.php on line 65"
```

I can prevent the warning with "@" as here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php. But is that right way? What's reason of this Warning? Maybe it have to be fix.